Getting empty spots when I try to bake normal map. Has anyone seen this before?

I have a high poly and a low poly model. I select the high poly model and then select the low poly model that has a new image texture active. When I click bake this is the result that I get. Both models have a multi rez and the high poly has a shrinkwrap. I've also tried it without any modifiers on. Both models have been UV unwrapped in the same way. The settings that I change under baking are setting the bake type from "combined" to "normals" and then giving the cage an offset of 0.1m

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Sorry but I don't feel comfortable sharing my files. I can send more screenshots though.

I figured it out. I'm not sure why I was getting the above result. But setting the multi rez to 0 for the viewport and then baking onto an image inside the high poly model with only the high poly model selected gave me a working normal map. Keeping this here in case any one else has this issue in the future.

Please just post that as an answer, so it's clearer that your question has been answered (and people can show their gratitude so you get reputation, if that's something you care about :).

Oh sorry, I don't use this site often, wasn't aware of that. I've added it as an answer now.

I figured it out. I'm not sure why I was getting the above result. But setting the multi rez to 0 for the viewport and then baking onto an image inside the high poly model with only the high poly model selected gave me a working normal map. Keeping this here in case any one else has this issue in the future.
